# Adding drawable tvdpi for in AOSP

Tags: android-source

i am trying to add drawable-tvdpi for an app in AOSP tree. But drwable-tvdpi is not reflected in the resulting apk resources.

When i try to build the same using eclipse i can see drawable-tvdpi  in the resulting apk resources.

Please let me know how to enable AOSP for adding drwable-tvdpi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse builds are for all types of devices, while building aosp is for a single type of device.
You need to edit **build/core/product_config.mk**.
search for **PRODUCT_AAPT_CONFIG** and add **tvdpi** to this variable.